# Store value in file entity field using a form

Tags: forms, files

Apologies in advance, this question probably has an obvious answer.

I am using a custom form with a 'managed_file' widget named 'image' to upload image files to the public file directory:

```
$image = file_load($form_state['values']['image']);  
$image->status = FILE_STATUS_PERMANENT;
file_save($image);
```

I am using File Entity Module to attach to image file entities a caption text field (the machine readable name is 'field_caption'). On the custom file upload form there is a 'textfield' widget named 'caption' whose submitted value I want to store as the value of the image file entity's 'field_caption'.

Certainly, Drupal needs to first realize that the uploaded file is in fact an *image* file, as other file entites might not have attached a caption text field. That's why in the code above I first save the file before the code is followed by

```
if (isset($form_state['values']['caption'])) {  
$caption = $form_state['values']['caption'];
$image->field_caption[0]['value'] = $caption;  
}
file_save($image);
```

However, after submission the caption text field is always left empty.

Did I choose the wrong commands to store a value in field_caption?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted this on drupal.org (https://drupal.org/node/1820706) and got an answer that works. I have to replace

```
$image->field_caption[0]['value'] = $caption;
```

with

```
$image->field_caption[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] = $caption;
```